# I added a comma, and the site went down

Tags: error

I added a comma, and my site went down. I was only recently granted an admin account, and am wondering if this could be related to my log-in permissions?

Comment: Where did you add the comma? In a channel entry? I find it hard to believe that adding a comma anywhere in the site could cause it to go down, but you may need to check with the person who granted you admin privileges and have them take a look into your problem. If you can provide more information I may be able to be more help.

Comment: Yes, I agree it seems a bit extreme. I clicked on the Home page and added the comma to some text there. I'm not sure if that's considered a channel entry or not. The head of IT is looking into it now. Thanks for commenting.

Comment: This would not be a log-in permissions error, however it could very well be an issue with the channel entry for the home page or an issue saving the entry to the database. What happens if you remove the comma? Are you able to do that? or did the admin section go down as well?

Comment: Make sure to avoid encoded commas in your URLs: http://ellislab.com/?%2C, or mistakenly putting two question marks: http://ellislab.com/??a

Answer (score 11):

Jesus Christ, never EVER enter a comma in EE. I bet you brought down gmail yesterday too.

Answer (score 2):

I did that once. I almost got my birthday taken away because of it. If you must add a comma, make sure you spell it out. In Pig Latin.

Ommacay

But make sure you don't have the Pig Latin add-on installed or EE will totally figure out your game and mess you up.

Answer (score 2):

You must be surfing the interwebs on Internet Explorer. It's a well known bug in IE that hammers IE users all of the time. Bill Gates is said to have personally taken up fight on excess comma's.
Maybe [these tips](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/57542/probably-excessive-commas-a-part-of-sentence-looks-like-a-list-of-items) can help